# Rails: where to store something global is controlled by controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oop, global-variables

I have `User`s in my app. Each of them has a Facebook profile (Koala is used for this).

So, I should store `graph` object anywhere. Next I should set facebook id for this graph. I do it from controller because user click "Sign in" and signs in.

Suppose `User` has `friends`: I want to get them by `user.friends`. This method should return facebook ids of user's friends. So, this method should use `graph`.

How to make all of this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... If I understood you correctly, you want to create and store global `@graph` object per User after he signs in. I think, we meet here with stateless property of HTTP protocol and one way to avoid it - using Rails `session` object. But this is wrong way in my mind.

Another way - create `@graph` every time after User signs in. And another way - using something middleware machinery, like [Redis](http://redis.io). You can store in Redis any information about User in string. For example, you can store in it set of User Facebook friends and get them any time you need.

But surely there is another way, I think )

Comment: but where to store `@graph`? in `session`? and how to get `session` from a `User` object?

Comment: I think, the best way for this case - create virtual attribute in the User model, and fill it with @graph object in place where User retrieved from the date base during authentication process.